# Python - get values from txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get some values from txt file where lines has specific string. My text file contains more data like below,

```
2018-11-11 00:00:10 INFO ProtocolProcessor:417 - PUBLISH on server 80 from clientID <ClientId> on topic </data/AClientData> with QoS MOST_ONE
2018-11-11 00:00:10 INFO ProtocolProcessor:530 - Received Msg:{
"id" : "A001",
"val" : 62.0,
"ts" : "2018-11-10 23:41:21"
}
2018-11-11 00:00:10 INFO ProtocolProcessor:587 - send publish message to <tcp://35.166.43.154:80> on topic </data/BClientData>
2018-11-11 00:00:11 INFO Consumer:39 - Received a message of type PUBLISH
2018-11-11 00:00:11 INFO Consumer:58 - String received before queue:{
"id" : "B001",
"val" : 89.0,
"ts" : "2018-11-10 23:42:21"
}
```

From above text I want to print **Received Msg:** as below format where line contains /data/AClientData

```
id =A001,
value = 62.0
date = 2018-11-10 23:41:21
```

Code Tried :

```
searchString = '/data/AClientData'
search = open("C:\\ReadLogUsingPython.txt","r")
for line in search.readlines():
    if searchString in line:
        #here need to take value of next line Received Msg:{ }
        #print each value
        valueDict ={"id" : "A001","val" : 62.0,"ts" : "2018-11-10 23:41:21"}
        print(valueDict['id'])
        print(valueDict['val'])
        print(valueDict['ts'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if "/data/AClientData" in line:
            next(infile)
            extractData = [next(infile).strip().replace('"', "") for i in range(3)]
            for i in extractData:
                print("{}={}".format(*i.split(" : ")))
```

**Output:**

```
id=A001,
val=62.0,
ts=2018-11-10 23:41:21
```

Comment: showing error  print("{}={}".format(*i.split(" : "))) IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: What does `print(i)` show? or can you show `extractData `

Answer (score 1):

To do something like this, I would scan character by character for the `<` and `>` fences, and then associate the content with a JSON parsed string fenced by `{` and `}`. For example

```
results = {}
fp = open('file.txt', 'r'):

char = fp.read(1)
nameStart, nameEnd, jStart, jEnd = None
while char:
    If char == '<'
        nameStart = fp.seek()
    elif char == '>':
        nameEnd = fp.seek()
    elif char == '{':
        jStart = fp.seek()
    elif char == '}':
        jEnd = fp.seek()
        # read the string between each start/end pair, parse json, and stash in results
    char = fp.read(1)
```

I typed this on a phone, so please forgive any errors. That's the rough idea though.